# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting an error like in Pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:/PycharmProjects/DemoPyth/PythonPack1/Prg1.py", line 3, in <module>     
driver=webdriver("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe") 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
```

My script is a simple one :

```
from selenium import webdriver   
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

As per *best practices* you must not **add**/**delete**/**modify** any of the *directories* / *sub-directories* / *files* created by *Python* until and unless you are aware how the change is going to effect *Python's* behavior.

You need to download the latest *ChromeDriver* from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and store it anywhere within your system. As you are on *Windows OS*, unzip the binary and perform the following:

- Ensure that you are invoking:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome() # not webdriver.chrome()
  ```
- Within your program, pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the **absolute path** of the *ChromeDriver*.
- While mentioning the **absolute path** of the *ChromeDriver*, either use *double back slashes* i.e. `\\`  within double quotes i.e. `" "`
- Or use *single back slash* i.e. `\` within single quotes i.e. `' '`
  along with the raw `r` switch as follows.
- So your code block will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Anindita\chromedriver.exe')
  ```