# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using ChromeDriver through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, module, selenium-chromedriver, callable

I have this problem show me error :

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How to solve that?

I use pycharm and try to change path for C:\Users\MOSTAFA\Desktop\chromedriver.exe and not working.

[image]

Comment: try to put chrome driver in save folder as program and call wit proper path

Comment: Please, share your code as text.

Comment: Chrome is not a module, it is a class. driver = webdriver.Chrome() https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

Single "\" as strings are considered escape sequences.

[Source](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html)

To avoid this, you need to use "\\" so python will consider it as "\".

```
driver  = webdriver.chrome("C:\\Users\\MOSTAFA\\Desktop\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
```

or just use "/" instead of "\"

```
driver  = webdriver.chrome("C:/Users/MOSTAFA/Desktop/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. You need to replace the lowercase **c** with uppercase **C** to initiate a [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controlled *Chrome* browsing context. So your effective line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\MOSTAFA\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
```

---

### Reference

You can find detailed discussion in:

- [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver(“C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243290/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-with-driver-webdriverc-pyth/51245550#51245550)