# How to address 'module' object not callable in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, callable

I have recently got a problem while working with selenium for making a Twitter bot. The code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.chrome(options=option)

driver.get("http://twitter.com/login")
```

The Error I have been getting is:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *`chrome()`* you need to call ***`Chome()`***

Your effective line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver("C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243290/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-with-driver-webdriverc-pyth/51245550#51245550)
- [How to resolve Selenium with Python: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649959/how-to-resolve-selenium-with-python-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable/59654170#59654170)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `chrome`, instead it should have been `Chrome`.

Not that it is `case-sensitive`.

Also, I see you are missing `--`

at this line

```
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

So, your code should be like this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

driver.get("http://twitter.com/login")
```