# Python selenium - How to run a Selenium Python Unittest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

I'm having an issue with running python selenium for the first time :

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import unittest

class segfam(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.chrome("/Users/tomersegal/Downloads/chromedriver")

    def test_blabla(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.il/")
        assert "Google" in driver.title
```

This is my error :

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest discover -s /Users/tomersegal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1 -t /Users/tomersegal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1 in /Users/tomersegal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1


Process finished with exit code 0

Empty suite
```

Comment: `Process finished with exit code 0` typically means there should not be any error. What is the error btw do you see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `unittest` framework you have to call it from the `__main__` function as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import unittest

class segfam(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/tomersegal/Downloads/chromedriver")

    def test_blabla(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.il/")
        assert "Google" in driver.title

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

> PS: Note the change of *chrome* to ***Chrome***

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python + WebDriver -- No browser launched while using unittest module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859370/python-webdriver-no-browser-launched-while-using-unittest-module/49860022#49860022)
- [What is unittest in selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503046/what-is-unittest-in-selenium-python/49516313#49516313)

Comment: now my error is : Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tomersegal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 7, in setUp
    self.driver=webdriver.chrome("/Users/tomersegal/Downloads/chromedriver")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: To address the error [_`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955750/how-to-address-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-using-selenium-a/69955953#69955953) See the note in the answer [_`PS: Note the change of chrome to Chrome`_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954694/how-to-address-module-object-not-callable-in-python-selenium/69954997#69954997)