# How to address TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, module, selenium-chromedriver, callable

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as Chromeoptions

chrome_options = Chromeoptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('Metamask.crx')

driver = webdriver.chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
driver.get("Https://www.youtube.com")

driver.quit()
```

This is the code I made, but I get this error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: You are calling `webdriver.chrome(...`, which is a module (as evident from `from selenium.webdriver.*chrome*.options import ...`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*chrome* is a module. Instead of that you need to call *`Chrome()`* as ***`webdriver.Chrome()`***

Your effective line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver("C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243290/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-with-driver-webdriverc-pyth/51245550#51245550)
- [How to resolve Selenium with Python: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649959/how-to-resolve-selenium-with-python-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable/59654170#59654170)